# Classical Yang-Mills equation of motion with both electric and magnetic sources?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, gauge-theory, yang-mills, classical-field-theory, magnetic-monopoles

We know the classical Maxwell equation of motion (eom) with both electric and magnetic source can be written as:

(1) Explicit form

[image]
or more schematically as:

(2) Differential form
$$
d * F = * J_e
$$
$$
dF =* J_m
$$

> My question is that do we have such classical Yang-Mills equation of motion with both electric and magnetic source in
>   both
>
> (1) Explicit form?
>
> (2) Differential form? Naively, we may write
>   $$
> D * F = * J_e
> $$
>   $$
> D F =* J_m
> $$
>   where $F= dA + A \wedge A$ and $D=d + [A, ]$ as the covariant derivative version of exterior derivative $d$.
>
> But: To be aware that for example, the $SU(2)$ Yang-Mills and $SO(3)$ Yang-Mills theory may have distinct constraint on the magnetic monopole (or the t Hooft loop). It does not seem to me that $J_e$ or $J_m$ contain such information?

Comment: Please clarify your question. Are you asking why the same equations can be written in such different forms?

Comment: No. But I am interested in knowing both (1) Explicit form and (2) Differential form for YM with e and m source

Comment: OK, that makes it clearer. Thank you. Do you really want the Yang-Mills equations written in terms of $\mathbf{E}$ and $\mathbf{B}$? They ate usually written in terms of $F^{\mu\nu}$.

Comment: written as $E^a$ and $B^a$ are preferred. But you can convert to $F$ first